# MVC, How to read rendered HTML in a controller?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, render

Maybe it´s a strange question, but imagine this:

```
//We all know that View is a method...
public ActionResult Something()
{
    return View("index");
}
```

But what if I step before this method to perform some stats

```
public ActionResult Something()
{
    return PerformStats(View("index"));
}
```

I will have a private method like this:

```
private ActionResult PerformStats(ViewResult viewResult)
{

    //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACCHIEVE:
    //*********************************

    var contentSent = viewResult.InnerHtml.Lengh; <<-- I wish!

    return viewResult;
}
```

And latter, what i want to do, is to save that ammount of content sent to the client.
It doesn´t matter if it is the exactly quantity of html, even if I get the .count() of a json it will do the trick.

Is any way to know the rendered content on the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, logging framework for the view??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to calculate Response length in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462995/simple-way-to-calculate-response-length-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnActionExecuting`: Called before action method executes. You can put stats related logic in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter.onactionexecuting(v=vs.98).aspx

`OnActionExecuted`: Called after action method executed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter.onactionexecuted(v=vs.98).aspx

Within these methods you can access `ActionExecuting` and `ActionExecutedContext`

If you want to get a size of rendered HTML (partial or complete view), then you probably need to:

- Find the view that you want to render
- Store it in the string builder
- Get its length

There is a question that explains how to render view as a string within the action method: [In MVC3 Razor, how do I get the html of a rendered view inside an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692131/in-mvc3-razor-how-do-i-get-the-html-of-a-rendered-view-inside-an-action)