# MVC FilterAttribute to get Response length

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 (.NET 4.5) application. I have a void Action on the controller that uses a simple `Response.Write()` method. I want to write a `FilterAttribute` that would check if the Response length is 0 in the `OnActionExecuted()` method. However, i can't seem to find a suitable `ActionExecutedContext` property to do this.
What i tried so far:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Length == 0)
    {
        Logger.Log("empty response detected");
    }
}
```

However, this throws a `Specified method is not supported.` exception. I foudn that this stream is write-only. What property should i check?

Comment: Why? Have you tried to create view or `ActionResult` that will write to `Response` as expected (instead of writing in controller)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeh i could probably subclass ActionResult. Laziness, really, this is prototype that just writes JSON out, but the app can't be a webapi, since other parts use actual views etc. So i add void Actions in which i serialize to JSON and Response.Write()

Comment: Hmm? Using [Controller.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936(v=vs.118).aspx) is more work that manually write correct JSON out?

Comment: The Content-Length response header is added by IIS at a much later stage. The reason for that is because IIS might for example apply compression to the output of your web application. So you cannot get the actual content length from your application. If on the other hand you want to get the length of the response stream your application has produced you could write a response filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter(v=vs.110).aspx Here's an example I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17463312/29407

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to calculate Response length in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462995/simple-way-to-calculate-response-length-in-mvc4)

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can't depend on the `HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Length` to get the response length because of the reason @Darin described. And even if you do get the length, that's not the length for the content body only so it wouldn't be accurate anyway.

I am going to show you how I would achieve a similar task: **email out at the end of the day if any of AJAX/JSON requests during the day exceeds 95% of the limits defined in the application**. Note: I am only checking for ajax requests, i.e., `JsonResult`.

### 1. Override default `MaxJsonLength` of `JsonResult`

The default `MaxJsonLength` of `JsonResult` is set to 102400 bytes (100k). So I need to override the `JsonResult`, especially `Json()` from the `Controller`. Hence I define a custom Mvc Controller for that.

```
public abstract class PowerfulControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            MaxJsonLength = JsonResultFilter.MaxJsonLengthInBytes
        };

    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
            MaxJsonLength = JsonResultFilter.MaxJsonLengthInBytes
        };
    }        
}
```

The `MaxJsonLength` is defined in the custom `ResultFilter` called `JsonResultFilter` I am going to show later.

## 2. Define a custom `JsonResult`

Since we can't count on the `Response` object to get the content body length, we have to somehow process the response data first. Hence here I will define a custom `JsonResult` class that uses **Newtonsoft** JSON Serializer to serialize the object/data.

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public int ContentLength { get; private set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        this.ContentLength = 0;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(base.ContentType)
            ? base.ContentType
            : "application/json";

        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(base.Data, Formatting.None);

        if (base.ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = base.ContentEncoding;

            this.ContentLength = response.ContentEncoding.GetByteCount(serializedObject);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(serializedObject);
        }

        response.Write(serializedObject);
    }
}
```

Here the new `JsonNetResult` has an additional property called `ContentLength` to contain the length of the content, after the serialization using `JsonConvert`.

Now we need to replace `JsonResult` in step 1 with this class.

```
public abstract class PowerfulControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult()
        {
            ...
        };
    }

    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult()
        {
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Now the `JsonResult` returned from this `PowerfulControllerBase` will have the special property called `ContentLength`. The last thing we need to do is to define a `ActionFilter`, more specially, a `ResultFilter`.

## 3. Define a Result Filter

We want to detect whenever the AJAX response content size is about to exceed the limit we definied. Hence we need to define a filter and inject it into the `GlobalFilterCollection`.

```
public class JsonResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public const int MaxJsonLengthInBytes = 15728640;    // 15360 k = 15 mb
    public const double AlertPercentage = .95;           // 95%

    // A service that records this warning
    private readonly ISystemWarningService _systemWarningService;

    public JsonResultFilter(ISystemWarningService systemWarningService)
    {
        _systemWarningService = systemWarningService;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // We're only interested in JsonNetResult
        if (filterContext.Result is JsonNetResult)
        {
            JsonNetResult jsonResult = filterContext.Result as JsonNetResult;
            // See if the content length exceeds the percentage of the limit
            if ((double)jsonResult.ContentLength / MaxJsonLengthInBytes >= AlertPercentage)
            {
                _systemWarningService.LogSizeWarning(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl,
                    filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
                    jsonResult.ContentLength,
                    MaxJsonLengthInBytes);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

All the warnings could be inserted into the database, for example, and you can define a SQL job that runs at the end of each day to send out email notification.

Comment: Like it said in the comments to the question, this pinnacles on the fact that you return a `ContentResult` subclass. I specifically wanted a way when we're writing to the response using `Response.Write()`.