# Read response body of HttpContext in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, response, httpcontext

I am creating an action filter that should read the response returned by an action, collect some data from it then log it, but I can't find anywhere where I could read the response body. I tried the following code to access a property name OutputStream at the respone in an HttpContext, but I keep getting error saying that Length property and Read method are not supported for this stream.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[filterContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Length];                                 
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())  
          { 
               int read; 
               while ((read = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)  
               { 
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
               }
               string html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());  
          }
    }
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930453/mvc-filterattribute-to-get-response-length help?

Comment: no, unfortunately.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462995/simple-way-to-calculate-response-length-in-mvc4 didn't help?

Comment: I have tried also this Filter property, but had the same problem. And this question is writing to the response not reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I can not extract from "Stream", so I decided to use "Result Data" to get the data to my Log.

```
public class LogResultFilter : IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var responseBody = string.Empty;
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResultBase)
        {
            responseBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result).ViewData);
        }

        if (filterContext.Result is JsonResult)
        {
            responseBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(((JsonResult)filterContext.Result));
        }

        // Continue...
```