# How to track down long running calls to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

Our users are restless.  They keep complaining about woolly, unmeasurable stuff, particularly slowness, without giving specifics, which of course makes it very difficult to track down.

Nonetheless, it is quite possible that they are right, that there are server calls that are taking way too long to come back.  So I want to put some kind of sniffer on the web site (we're using ASP.NET MVC 4 on IIS7) that will log any call that takes more than *n* seconds to turn around, or that returns more than *x* megabytes of data, along with all request parameters, the response size, and maybe a certain amount of response data.

I haven't a clue how to do this, though.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is my take on this:

**FRT**

While you can use failed request tracing to log slow requests, in my experience is more useful for finding out why a request fails before it hits your application, rather than why its running slowly. 9/10 times its going to simply show you that the slowdown is in your code somewhere.

**Log Parser**

Yes you can download and analyze iis logs. I use [Log Parser Lizard](http://www.logparserlizard.com/) to do the analysis - its a great gui over log parser. Here's a sample of how you might query slow requests over 1000ms:

```
SELECT
  To_String(To_timestamp(date, time), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') As Time,
  cs-uri-stem, cs-uri-query, cs-method, time-taken, cs-bytes,  sc-status
FROM 
  'C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex140721.log'
WHERE 
  time-taken > 1000 
ORDER BY time-taken desc
```

**New Relic**
My recommendation - go easy on yourself and sign up for a [free trial](https://newrelic.com/signup). No I don't work for them, but I've used their APM product a lot. Install the agent on the server - set it up. In 10 mins you will be amazed at the data you see about the site. Trust me.

Its designed to work in production environments and gives you amazing depth of info on what's running slow, down to the database query and stack traces. Its pure awesome. Once its setup wait for the next user complaint, log in and look at traces for the time frame.

When your pro trial ends, you can still get valuable data on the free tier, but it will only keep last 24 hours. We purchased licenses -expensive yes, but worth every cent. Why? Time taken to identify root causes was reduced by an order of magnitude, we can get proactive by looking at what is number 2, 3 and 4 on the slow requests list and working those before they become big problems, and finally the alerting makes us much more responsive when things were going wrong.

**Code it**

You could roll you own. This [blog](http://www.paulallen.org/blog/capture-and-log-requests-and-responses-aspnet-mvc-3) uses Mvc ActionFilters to do the logging. You could also use an HttpModule similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462995/simple-way-to-calculate-response-length-in-mvc4). The nice thing about this approach is you can compile and implement the module separately from your application, and then just drop in the dll and update web.config to wire up the module. I would be wary of these approaches for a very busy site. Also, getting the right level of detail to fully identify the root is challenging.

**View Requests**

As touched on by Appleman1234, IIS has a little known [feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732518(v=ws.10).aspx) to look at requests currently executing. Its handy for the 'hey its running slow right now' situation. You can use appcmd.exe or the IIS gui to do it. You will need to install the 'Request Monitor' IIS feature for this to work. This approach is ok for rudimentary narrowing of the problem, but does not show you whats running slowly in your controller.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going with New Relic, looks great so far!

Comment: Cool - I think you won't look back. I found that delving into NR was addictive, always looking for how to improve perf.

Comment: Well, my experience with NR is not going so well.  Would you mind taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28008976/7850) and telling me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to hear this. I have hit this issue and will reply to your new question.

Comment: I am rather annoyed that there are approximately 5 answers in here. If it were broken up, I'd upvote at least one of the answers. Since I haven't tried all (or even _most_ of your methods), I cannot endorse this post.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways you can do this:

- Failed Requests Tracing(FRT) – formerly known as Failed Request Event Buffering (FREB) with custom failure condition of takes over a certain time to load / run
- Logging request information with IIS logging functionality and then using a tool like LogParserStudio
- Using tools like Fiddler or IISMonitor on the IIS server to capture request information

For FRT the official documentation is available [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and information how to capture dumps for long running process is avaliable [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/08/04/iis7-and-above-using-freb-to-capture-dumps-for-a-long-running-request.aspx)

For logging request information in IIS information about log file analysis is located [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2014/02/06/how-to-analyse-iis-logs-using-logparser-logparser-studio.aspx)

For information on configuring Fiddler to capture IIS requests find information [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-fiddler-with-iis/)

A summary of the steps in the linked resources is provided below.

**For FRT**

From IIS Manager for a given site,In the Actions pane, under Configure, click Failed Request Tracing and enter desired values in dialog box to enable Failed Request Tracing.

From IIS Manager for a given site, under IIS click Failed Request Tracing Rules, in order to define rules of failure for a given request. In the Actions pane, click Add and follow the wizard.

The logs will go in the directory you specify and are viewable in a web broswer.

**For IIS logging**

Logging is enabled by default on IIS

From IIS Manager for a given site,under IIS click Logging, and in the Actions Pane, click Enable to enable logging if it isn't already.

From IIS Manager for a given site,under IIS click Logging, and then configure as desired and click apply.

Install [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659), [.Net 4.x](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=181012) and [LogParserStudio](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765) (if you need additional steps see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/karywa/archive/2013/04/21/getting-started-with-log-parser-studio.aspx)

Open LogParserStudio and add logs to it, you then can use SQL queries to get information from the log files.

**For Fiddler**

You need to change the user that IIS runs as to a user that can launch applications, like Fiddler (instead of Network Service), and then launch Fiddler with that user.

Also see [Monitor Activity on a Web Server (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for further information.