# Get page size of URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can we get the page size of a requested URL If that URL is returning a View?

```
eg: localhost:800/Home/Index/3
```

the above URL will return some ViewResult.then how can we get the size of response from server side including Model data.

Comment: Do you want to know what will be the Content-length? And where do you need that, in javascript or on the server?

Comment: @Nilesh I want total size on server side.

Comment: Did you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462995/simple-way-to-calculate-response-length-in-mvc4)